How to find a solution to the functional equation $f(x-a)=-1/f(x)$
Im assuming that $f$ is a "piecewise continuous"  (I dont know the English term) function and $x$ and $a$ element of the real numbers. I noticed that this equation is true for $\tan(x)$ with $a$ being $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I'm assuming there is a general solution in form of a scaled and or shifted tangent function for any $a$.
Equation:  $f(x-a)=-\frac{1}{f(x)}$

If $a>0$, take any function on $[0,a)$ (with no zeros) and try to define it on the whole line using the given equation.

$f(x)$ cannot be fully continuous as any $x_0$ with $f(x_0)=0$ would make $f(x_0-a)=f(x_0+a)=-\frac10$ while elsewhere there must be sign changes.

@YvesDaoust I missed the hypothesis 'piecewise continuous'. Thanka for pointing out.

$\tan x$ is not defined at certain points, so it is not considered as a  solution.

Assume $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.
Define $f:D=\left(-\frac{\pi}{2a}, \frac{\pi}{2a}\right)\to \mathbb{R}, \quad x\longmapsto \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2a}x\right)$.
This fuction is continuous on $D$ and:
$$f(x-a)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2a}(x-a)\right)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2a}x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2a}x\right)=-\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2a}x\right)}=-\frac{1}{f(x)} $$
$\forall x\in D$.
Moreover, you can extend the function to $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{\text{zeros of}\space f(x)\}$ for periodicity and obtain a piecewise continuous function.

Yes, I am aware of that. But I want to know if you can find this solution without the guess/Ansatz approach. Or maybe a more general solution.

My guess is that maybe we can generalize a bit more the solution involving the tangent, but that condition it is not verified by polynomials, exponentials or any other standard functions. So, maybe that is the only class of solution. An approach with more general tools is probably needed.
